Completely block a window to soundproof it
I have a large patio sliding glass door / window and it's making sound isolation so so so much worse than it should be. If it were just a piece of wall, then soundproofing would be a lot better. So I'm wondering how to cover up the window so it's basically just a piece of wall. I'm thinking like a big sheet of metal of steel but I'm not sure where to buy that.

Are you looking for a permanent solution, or something temporary that can be easily (re)moved?

@Huesmann I am a renter, so it'd need to be somewhat temporary with no lasting impact to the room/building.

If the window is set back from the wall, I would consider getting some of that pink foam insulation board and some rockwool.  Stick the rockwool up against the window and cover with the foam board.  You could use drywall, but the foam board may be easier to deal with because you can just jam it in there and it's a lot lighter.  Depending how pretty you want, you could even just leave the rockwool with the facing toward the interior and paint it to match the wall.

The thing that stops sound is a combination of mass and isolation. Mass reduces vibration which reduces high frequency sound being coupled through; isolation reduces how much low frequency sound comes through.
As a low budget very partial solution, simply putting very heavy drapes over the entire patio door will reduce sound transmission somewhat.
If you want to go beyond that, I think your simplest solution might be to frame up what amounts to a freestanding segment of wall that you could slide over that patio door. Past answers have described how to use offset studs  to reduce sound transmission through the framing. There are other things you could do if you were closing this opening more permanently, but I presume that you don't want to or aren't allowed to alter the building that much.
Note that your existing walls are probably not built for sound isolation, so just putting something in to soak up the sound from this door may not have as much effect as you hope. Again, see past answers.


I'm thinking like a big sheet of metal

haha, don't do that.

So I'm wondering how to cover up the window so it's basically just a piece of wall.

um, drywall.

Your answer is vague enough to be unhelpful. You offer no details about how one would cover a door with drywall, and the suggestion to do so is sketchy in the first place.

well, if the [large] patio door (whose dimensions were not specified) is less than a 4x8 sheet of drywall then you could just lay it up against the wall and fasten it with screws to the existing studs behind the drywall at the corners of the patio door.  Otherwise frame in with studs and put verticals where needed to accomodate however many 4x8 sheets of drywall to accommodate "walling" it off.  I did not think I would have to explain it.  Then again if the OP provided more detail to his probrem then I would've provided more detail.

I'm wondering how to cover up the window so it's basically just a piece of wall ... um, like, just wall it off dude

All that information (aside from the snark) belongs in your answer, not down here in a comment. You've complained in the past about your contributions not being received well. Here's a great case study.

oh i don't think it was complaining.  It was more like pointing out the hypocrisy and the upvote cult that exists here.  I mean c'mon, 5 upvotes for heavy drapes as an answer to what was how to cover up the window so it's basically just a piece of wall

@ron haha, don't do that. ... why not?

if you think sheet metal is good at soundproofing then there would not be all the how do I soundproof my metal building or metal roof.  Metal most of the time, sheet especially, does not soundproof.  And for metal sound proofing you would need to start with 1/2" steel at 20 lbs per sq ft.  Or show me some example where metal alone is used to soundproof.

for example compare cars that were all metal pre 1980's and the interior sound quality to any car today.., metal phaseout to plastic and what is body metal all the sound dampening that then goes into that part to make for a quiet interior.

or take a ford/chvy/dodge 3/4 ton style work van which has an uninsulated un-dampen'd metal roof.  ever been in one of those when it rains, especially when they are empty?  if you've ever wondered why a jobber driving in such a work truck (van) was hostile on the road... that sort of noise can and will drive you crazy after an amount of time.
